# UserManager's async methods giving "Incorrect number of arguments for call to method Boolean Equals"

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've made custom User and UserStore classes.
Now I'm trying to register or login with a user, but I get the error

> 'Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method Boolean
>   Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

The error is on line 411:

```
Line 409:       }
Line 410:       var user = new User() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
--> Line 411:      IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
Line 412:       if (result.Succeeded)
Line 413:       {
```

I get this same error on

```
UserManager.FindAsync(user), UserManager.CreateAsync(user,password)
```

Now the error *doesn't* occur when I log in with an External Login, like Google, which also uses methods from UserManager. Entering the email works as well, but when the user has to be created from an External Login with the inserted email, it gives the `CreateAsync` error too.

---

EDIT The error also occurs on `UserManager.Create(User user)`

---

This is probably because the method in UserManager does an Equal on the user object's id, while it is expecting a string and mine is an int. But because I can't get a stacktrace inside the UserManager, and I have no idea how to override this method in the UserManager, I do not know how to solve this?

How can I fix this? Do I need to create my own UserManager? Or do I need another solution entirely?

My userstore code:

```
public class UserStore :
IUserStore<User>,
IUserPasswordStore<User>,
IUserSecurityStampStore<User>,
IUserEmailStore<User>,
IUserLoginStore<User>
{
    private readonly NFCMSDbContext _db;
    public UserStore(NFCMSDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public UserStore()
    {
        _db = new NFCMSDbContext();
    }

    #region IUserStore
    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        _db.Users.Add(user);
        _db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public Task DeleteAsync(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        _db.Users.Remove(user);
        _db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        return _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    public Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        int userid;
        if(int.TryParse(userId,out userid))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userId");

        return _db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == userid).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
(...)
```

User.cs:

```
public sealed class User : IUser<int>
{
    public User()
    {
        UserLogins = new List<UserLogin>();
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public string Email {get; set; }
    public bool IsEmailConfirmed { get; set; }

    int IUser<int>.Id
    {
        get { return UserId; }
    }

    public ICollection<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; private set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change your UserManager type to UserManager to tell it that your user key is now int instead of string?

Comment: That's the problem. UserManager is a class in the closed DLL Microsoft.AspNet.Identity. I've already used Resharper to decompile this, but it shows no string equalising. So, I have no idea how to tell UserManager that some values have changed and I'm not even sure that these changes to the User model are the cause of the error.